# ViewBag perdendo referência após envio de formulário. Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5, razor

Olá, possuo duas ViewBags que estão guardando uma lista cada uma, eu carrego elas em um formulário para fazer um select box, junto delas tem um botão de Remover. Até ai tudo bem, porém quando eu clico no botão da primeira ViewBag, ocorre um erro de perda de referência, já a segunda ViewBag esta funcionando 100% perfeito.

View:

```
<label>Especializações:</label>
@{
    if (((List<ProfessionalSpecialization>)ViewBag.ListProfessionalSpecialization).Count > 0)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveProfessionalUserSpecializations", "ProfessionalUser", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="display:inline">
                <nav class="mainmenu" style="width: 246px; margin: auto; position: relative; max-width: 100%;">
                    <select id="specialization" class="form-control" name="specialization">
                        @foreach (ProfessionalSpecialization item in (List<ProfessionalSpecialization>)ViewBag.ListProfessionalSpecialization)
                        {
                            <option>@item.Title</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Remover</button>
                </nav>
            </div>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <label>Você não possui especializações cadastradas.</label>
    }
}
<label>Áreas:</label>
@{
    if (((List<ProfessionalType>)ViewBag.ListProfessionalType).Count > 0)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveProfessionalUserTypes", "ProfessionalUser", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="display:inline">
                <nav class="mainmenu" style="width: 246px; margin: auto; position: relative; max-width: 100%;">
                    <select id="type" class="form-control" name="type">
                        @foreach (ProfessionalType item in (List<ProfessionalType>)ViewBag.ListProfessionalType)
                        {
                            <option>@item.Title</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Remover</button>
                </nav>
            </div>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <label>Você não possui áreas cadastradas.</label>
    }
}
```

O que acontece é que se clicado no submit do segundo formulário, ele segue tudo bem, se clicado no primeiro, ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
>   if (((List)ViewBag.ListProfessionalSpecialization).Count > 0)

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    ProfessionalUser pUser = new ProfessionalUser();
    using (ProfessionalUserDAO pUserDAO = new ProfessionalUserDAO())
    {
        pUser = pUserDAO.ListProfessionalUserById(id);
    }
    List<ProfessionalSpecialization> listSpecializationsOfUser = new List<ProfessionalSpecialization>();
    List<ProfessionalSpecialization> listAllSpecializations = new List<ProfessionalSpecialization>();
    List<ProfessionalType> listTypesOfUser = new List<ProfessionalType>();
    List<ProfessionalType> listAllTypes = new List<ProfessionalType>();

    using (ProfessionalUserDAO dao = new ProfessionalUserDAO())
    {
        try
        {
            using (ProfessionalSpecializationDAO sDAO = new ProfessionalSpecializationDAO())
            {
                listAllSpecializations = sDAO.ListProfessionalSpecialization(0);
                foreach (int idToGetSpecialization in pUser.Specializations)
                {
                    listSpecializationsOfUser.Add(sDAO.ListProfessionalSpecializationById(idToGetSpecialization));
                }
            }

            using (ProfessionalTypeDAO tDAO = new ProfessionalTypeDAO())
            {
                listAllTypes = tDAO.ListProfessionalType(0);
                foreach (int idToGetType in pUser.Types)
                {
                    listTypesOfUser.Add(tDAO.ListProfessionalTypeById(idToGetType));
                }
            }

            ViewBag.ListAllSpecializations = listAllSpecializations;
            ViewBag.ListProfessionalSpecialization = listSpecializationsOfUser;
            ViewBag.ListAllTypes = listAllTypes;
            ViewBag.ListProfessionalType = listTypesOfUser;
            return View(ProfessionalUser.UserLogged);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

Actions que vão os forms:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveProfessionalUserSpecializations(FormCollection form)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && form != null)
    {
        string spec = form["specialization"].ToString();
        using (ProfessionalUserDAO dao = new ProfessionalUserDAO())
        {
            dao.RemoveSpecializationFromUser(spec);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = ProfessionalUser.UserLogged.IdProfessionalUser });
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveProfessionalUserTypes(FormCollection form)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && form != null)
    {
        string type = form["type"].ToString();
        using (ProfessionalUserDAO dao = new ProfessionalUserDAO())
        {
            dao.RemoveTypeFromUser(type);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = ProfessionalUser.UserLogged.IdProfessionalUser });
}
```

Comment: Só pra eu entender: você tem duas `Actions`, sendo uma chamada `RemoveProfessionalUserTypes` e outra chamada `RemoveProfessionalUserSpecializations`? Em ambas todos os elementos da `ViewBag` são carregados?

Comment: Cada Action trata uma ViewBag diferente.

Comment: Esta `Action` que você colocou é qual delas?

Comment: Esta action é a action que carrega as listas para as ViewBags, porém as "Removes" nem coloquei aqui. Quando dou o submit no formulário de baixo ele entra no "RemoveProfessionalUserType", mas se for clicado no submit do form de cima ele da erro, nem chega a entrar na Action, coloco o breakpoint e da o erro antes de entrar na action, eu não entendo nem por que ele entra no if de novo, pois da erro neste if.

Comment: sim as duas estão no controler.Não não tenho mano. =/

Comment: Descobri o Erro, estes 2 forms estão dentro de um outro, por algum motivo o primeiro estava sendo anulado!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido retirando os 2 forms de dentro de um outro form que não aparece na questão, ou seja, não pudemos ter 1 form pai com 2 outros dentro, ao menos neste caso.